# DocuSign Signature Is not Replacing usign Rest API PDF Form Fields

Tags: c#, rest, api, docusignapi

I have one PDF which is having a Signature Field, with Field label SignFlags. I would  like to send that PDF for DocuSign Signing Ceremony. I can sent the document for Signing process. But that Signature field does not have any Docusign Signature Tab.

JSON Request below:

```
'compositeTemplates': [{
    'inlineTemplates': [{
        'sequence': '1',
        'recipients': {
            'signers': [{
                'email': 'Test@gmail.com',
                'name': 'SignFlags',
                'recipientId': '1',
                'defaultRecipient': 'true',
                 'tabs':{
                         'signHereTabs':[
                            {
                               'tabLabel':''SignFlags'

                            }
                         ]}    
            }]
        }
    }],
    'document': {
        'documentId': '1',
        'name': 'irs_f4506t.pdf',
        'documentBase64':'" + document64+@"',
        'transformPdfFields': 'true'
    }
```

Why it is not placing Docusign Tab

Comment: Have you tried with Fixed Positioning method ?

Comment: Fixed positioning is a kind of finding the position of an element and place signature there right.I did not try that, but why this is not working?

Comment: Hold on a sec- This json is not valid. You should have used `"` instead of `'`

Comment: No that will work either with single quotes or double quotes

Comment: You can check here, Json in your question is not valid - https://jsonlint.com/